# Provider value not being forwarded to Consumer or useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Code:

```
const ThemeContext = createContext(null);

const ThemeProvider = ({ theme, ...restProps }) => {
  const props = {
    ...restProps,
    className: `theme-${theme}`,
  };

  console.info("className =", props.className); // this resulst in "className = theme-dark"

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
      <div className={props.className}>{props.children}</div>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const themeContext = useContext(ThemeContext);

  console.info("themeContext =", themeContext); // this results in "themeContext = undefined"

  return (
    <div>
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {(theme) => {
          console.info("my theme =", theme); // this results in "my theme = undefined"
          return (
            <>
              <p>MY THEME IS: {theme}</p>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemeProvider theme="dark">
        <MyComponent />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For some reason the console.info shows the following:

```
className = theme-dark
App.js:330 themeContext = undefined
App.js:336 my theme = undefined
```

I'm at a loss as to why my context value is not propagating from the provider to the consumer properly?

Comment: You've explicitly _removed_ `theme` from the `restProps` you then spread into `props` (which you don't actually use as a whole object anyway)... Try `console.info("props =", props)`, then `<ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>`.

Comment: Or to put it another way: it _is_ propagating the value you've given to it, which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `undefined` from `useContext(ThemeContext)` is because in the `ThemeProvider` you are setting the context's value to `undefined`, because there is no `theme` property in the `props` object:

```
const props = {
  ...restProps,
  className: `theme-${theme}`,
};
```

The reason is - you destructured `theme` property in the `ThemeProvider`'s arguments:

`const ThemeProvider = ({ theme, ...restProps })`

You can fix it by passing `theme` instead of `props.theme` to `<ThemeContext.Provider>`:
`<ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>`